# Why does this project appear to have links to files in another project?

Tags: xamarin.android

This is the TaskyPro solution, available here: https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/TaskyPro/

If you look at the solution structure on GitHub it doesn't have anything odd about it, but when I load the solution in Visual Studio it appears as follows:

[image]

The Tasky.Android project contains the same folders as the Tasky.Core project, and it appears to have links to the files in Tasky.Core. However, when I view the folders in Windows Explorer they are empty. If I view the properties of the links, the Full Path property points to the actual file stored in the Tasky.Core project.

Why are these links here? Can I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File linking is a way to share the same files across multiple projects without having to maintain multiple copies of each file by hand. In this case, it allows you to compile the same source files for both .NET and Android. Xamarin has a lot of documentation on this, including [this article](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/case_study%3a_tasky) which describes how Tasky is architected and implemented. I also recommend reading this guide on [Sharing Code Options](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options).